# Draw triangles in Paint.NET?

Tags: images, graphics, paint.net

I downloaded the Polygon / Stars plug-in but it only let's you draw equilateral triangles. Is there a plug-in or method that let's you create any kind of triangle? I can't just use the line tool because it makes the edges of the shape (the vertices of the shape) round or irregular instead of pointy.

Answer (score 0):

[BoltBait's plugin pack](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?showtopic=8318)

You can find a polygon tool in this pack.

Comment: The Polygon plugin in that pack is what I mentioned in the question...it can only make equilateral triangles